# Is there a 8 bit block sized Public-Private key encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, encryption-asymmetric, public-key-encryption

I checked out TripleDES. It's block size is of 64 bits.

Is there any algorithm for 8 bits block size?

Thanks

EDIT : I intend not to use this for perfect protection, but for a just-in-case situation where one who sees the code should not find the plaintext. So 8 bit is kinda okay for me.

Comment: Maybe you could add some information about what you would like to do with the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA with 8-bit key :)

Seriously though, the block-based cyphers are stateless - the ciphertext of a block depends only on the cleartext of the block, not on the previous blocks (otherwise it would be a stream cypher). A block cypher that acts on 8-bit blocks can be brute-forced easily, so there's no point.

Comment: Can we implement 8 Bit RSA in .NET??

Comment: I don't think so. And, like I and Thoman already said, it's almost like no encryption at all.

Answer (score 6):

A block cipher with 8-bit blocks means that each input block can be encrypted into 256 possible values -- which means that an attacker has a 1/256 chance of guessing the input value. It turns out to be very difficult to use such an algorithm securely. Nevertheless it is [possible](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/2007-fse-granboulan+pornin.pdf) to define a block cipher over 8-bit blocks, and to do it "perfectly"; just do not expect it to be generally useful.

There also are "block-less" ciphers, known as "stream ciphers" which encrypt data "byte by byte" (or even "bit by bit"); most are just pseudo-random generators which produce an arbitrary amount of bytes from a key. That generated stream is just to be combined with the data to encrypt with a XOR. The traditional stream cipher is RC4; but [newer and better](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) stream ciphers have been designed.

A block cipher, by itself, is a mathematical tool. In order to actually encrypt data, the block cipher must be used properly. The keywords are *chaining* and *padding*. Chaining is about defining what actually goes into the block cipher and what to do with the output. Padding is about adding some bytes to the data, in a reversible way, so that the padded message length is appropriate for the chosen chaining mode. The traditional chaining mode is  called [CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining). A newer (and arguably better) chaining mode is CTR (same link), which has the added bonus of avoiding the need for padding (CTR just turns a block cipher into a stream cipher).

As for block ciphers, you should use [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) instead of TripleDES. It is faster, more secure, and the current American standard.